# Как заполнить ячейки Nan в выбранных столбцах вышестоящими значениями в этих же столбцах?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть большой файл (пример привёл). Вопрос - как заполнить пустые ячейки в выбранных столбцах вышестоящими значениями в этих же столбцах по типу экселевской формулы замещения `(=ЕСЛИ(H3="нет данных";;H3))`?
Например, если в столбце "День" в строке 1 значение ячейки Nan, то заполнить её значением из верхней ячейки строки 0 указанной датой, чтобы получить в строке 1 такую же дату, что и в строке 0 столбца "День".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать метод `.fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
df['день'] = df['день'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Можно применить сразу ко всему датафрему, а не к отдельному столбцу;

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Он будет заполнять пропуски предыдущими значениями.

Comment: Есть короткий синоним `.ffill()` аналогичный коду `.fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, постараюсь запомнить)